# Getting a “You have not created a bootloader stage 1 target device” error when trying to install Fedora 19

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, uefi, efi

I am using a Lenovo z500 I want to install fedora 19 to my HDD but I get errors:

1. “You have not created a bootloader stage 1 target device.”
2. “sda6 must have one of the following disklabel types: GPT.”

I tried:

- Create 1-2 mb BIOS boot partition. (does not work)
- Change UEFI to Legacy first in BIOS (USB does not boot)
- Delete `BOOTX64.efi` in EFI folder in bootable USB (USB does not boot)
- Use other USB creator - unebootin, lili usb, linux live usb creator (does not work)

Where is the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [self-solved by the end-user as indicated in this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/642296/fedora-19-you-have-not-created-a-bootloader-stage-1-target-device#comment804237_642306) from pretty much 10 years ago and it was an idiosyncratic issue to begin with.

Comment: Maybe you can add to your question why you don't do automatic partitioning. You said in the comments of the answer that you disabled UEFI. This is not a good idea. You should use UEFI and disable legacy instead. As the name says legacy is old and deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you've booted the installer in EFI mode, which requires an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) to be bootable. If you're partitioning manually, you should be sure to create the ESP, which is a FAT32 partition with a type code of EF00 (in `gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk`) or that has its "boot flag" set (in `parted`, GParted, or most other libparted-based tools). You may also need to flag the ESP as such in Anaconda, but I don't recall the details of how to do that in Anaconda's user interface. You'll need to undo the things you said you tried (except for creating a BIOS Boot Partition; that's harmless, except for the waste of disk space it represents).

Comment: I solved it! **I used another usb**. After it I changed UEFI to Legaci first in bios. Usb booted and i created 3 partitions:

 - 120 mb (/boot)
 - 4 gb (swap)
 - 45GB (/  fedora install)

It was easy finally. But thanks for help.